# Servlet Filters in OSGi Enabled Web Application on Glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, servlet-filters, wab

I am creating some REST web services on Glassfish Jersey. I managed to create Web application bundle for my service. But I need to add some Servlet Filter to it. 
I couldn't find any information regarding this question based on Glassfish. I have seen some examples using Apache Felix Osgi Web Container but Glassfish does not use this bundle at all.
For osgi web conainer I use default Glassfish Fighterfish.

So how should I apply Servlet Filer on Web application bundle?

Thank you for the answers :)

P.S. I do not want to use SPRING. But I use Apache Aries blueprint capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the normal web.xml with filter and filter-mapping elements like in a normal servlet container. They should work in a wab project.